# How to clear large data from jqgrid table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The data that is coming as part of ajax call from my business class is as follows:

```
[{
    "user_action": "<button class='detail-icon' title='Vehicle Pass           History'onclick='javascript:openPopUpWagonList(&#39;DIM  008065&#39;);'> <img  src='/WIMS/images/icon_detail.png'></button>",
    "VEHICLE_ID": "DIM  008065",
    "setFlag": "<img src='/WIMS/images/wims-tick.gif'>",
    "clrFlag": "<img src='/WIMS/images/wims-tick.gif'>",
    "setDate": "31 Jul 2010 11:11",
    "lastClearDate": "24 Aug 2010 07:26",
    "noOfdays": "24",
    "ownerCode": "",
    "operatorCode": "",
    "maintainerCode": "",
    "severity10Pass": "~",
    "plot": "<button class='detail-icon' title='Plot' alt='Detail'onclick='javascript:popUpStepChangeListGraph(&#39;DIM  008065&#39;);'> <img src='/WIMS/images/icon_detail.png'></button>",
    "activeFlag": "1"
}, {
    "user_action": "<button class='detail-icon' title='Vehicle Pass History'onclick='javascript:openPopUpWagonList(&#39;N    005276&#39;);'> <img src='/WIMS/images/icon_detail.png'></button>",
    "VEHICLE_ID": "N    005276",
    "setFlag": "<img src='/WIMS/images/wims-tick.gif'>",
    "clrFlag": "",
    "setDate": "31 Aug 2011 10:05",
    "lastClearDate": "24 Mar 2011 10:45",
    "noOfdays": "0",
    "ownerCode": "",
    "operatorCode": "",
    "maintainerCode": "",
    "severity10Pass": "~~~",
    "plot": "<button class='detail-icon' title='Plot' alt='Detail'onclick='javascript:popUpStepChangeListGraph(&#39;N    005276&#39;);'> <img src='/WIMS/images/icon_detail.png'></button>",
    "activeFlag": "1"
}]
```

Here I have taken only 2 records for convenient readability, but I am displaying more than 150 records of this kind.

Now my ajax call format from my jsp page is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",    
    url: f_reqAction, // url is set already    
    data : {maintainer:maintainerValue,show:showValue},    
    dataType:'json',    
    async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/     
    cache: false,
    timeout:80000, /* Timeout in ms */
    success: handleApplyEventResponse,
    error: handleResponseError
});

function handleApplyEventResponse(response) {
    // response is coming from my business class
    $("#stepChangeData").jqGrid('clearGridData');
    if(response.length > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            jQuery("#stepChangeData").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,response[i]);
        }  
        $('#stepChangeData').setGridParam({rowNum:response.length});
    }
}
```

When I want to remove the data by calling `jQuery("#gridtabID").jqGrid('clearGridData');` a javascript error is coming prompting  to stop running the script. but if the data size is small like 20 or 30 the problem does not come.

I understand populating response data by calling `jqGrid('addRowData'` inside for loop is not efficient when the data is this much large. but i could not find a jqgrid api which can add this response data directly in the grid without any looping.

And i could not create the buttons contained in my json data through formatter option of `colModel` as I found it extremely difficult to create that type of button by formatter.So I created it in my business ligic and sending it to jsp page with json data as part of the ajax respose.

So in the above context, I would have loved to have an api which could have set this json data into the grid at a shot (i.e without any looping). And I think this way this script problem could have been averted as well.

Comment: **Which** error do you get?! Besides that, it would have been nice if you had formatted the code instead of posting just an unreadable blob of text.

Comment: Can you post your jQGrid definition and the code that cause the error?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and sorry for not formatting. as part of my implementatiion i am clearing the grid before adding new data into the grid. but  when    jQuery("#gridtabID").jqGrid('clearGridData');

Comment: You need to refresh your grid with new data? Can't you use $("#gridtabID").trigger("reloadGrid") ?

Comment: sorry my last comment is unfinished and by mistake i pressed enter key. to be continued from last.. but when jQuery("#gridtabID").jqGrid('clearGridData'); gets called internrt explorer dialog comes. it reads - stop running the script? otherwise your system will become unresponsive. if i press yes it comes out if no then again the alert box comes and the new data eventually gets loaded after a delay of 5-6 sec. by commenting and uncommenting jQuery("#gridtabID").jqGrid('clearGridData'), i understood that the problem lies there only. but for my purpose i want this api to be called. plz help

Comment: *Please include the JavaScript code which shows how you create jqGrid and how you fill it.* I suppose the origin of your problem is therein. Typically you don't need ever call `clearGridData`. I suppose that you chosen some extremely uneffective way to fill the grid. If you choose some better way then filling or clearing of about 1000 rows will be very quickly. Additionally I would don't recommend you to use HTML fragments inside of the grid data. You can better use custom formatter for example.

Comment: function handleApplyEventResponse(response){ $("#gridID").jqGrid('clearGridData'); if(response.length > 0){ 
  for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
      jQuery("#gridID").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,response[i]); }
  } } here the response is an ajax response containing the json string that i have posted earlier. this function is clearing the grid and adding the data after that. this ajax call is not going through url propertry to jqgrid, this is $.ajax{...} call of jquery hence $("#gridtabID").trigger("reloadGrid") has no use.

Comment: Please click on "edit" link under the text of your question and append your question with additional information (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)). Please format your code like it is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495). About your main problem: do you get the data with **separate** ajax request to the server? The usage of `addRowData` is exactly the most uneffective way what I mean. The execution time have **exponent complexity** depending on the number of rows of the grid. You should fill the grid in *one* operation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to fill jqGrid with the JSON data from the server to use `datatype: 'json'` and *load* the data from the server. jqGrid is very flexible and one can load practically *any* data. One need just to use corresponding `jsonReader` or `jsonmap` property of `colModel`. Sometimes one need additionally use `ajaxGridOptions` option, `serializeGridData` or `beforeProcessing` callbacks. One should additionally use `gridview: true` option of jqGrid.

The difference to the usage of `addRowData` is huge. The main disadvantage of the usage of `addRowData` is that the data will be placed in the grid row per row. The problem is that if you modify an element on the page or insert a new one *the position of all existing elements on the page have to be recalculated* by the web browser. Because you use `addRowData` in the loop, then positing of the row which will be inserted first have to be recalculated also after any insertion of the next rows. So The more rows need be inserted the more slowly will be the code. Because of the problem jQuery 1.4 introduced the method [jQuery.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) which allows to remove temporary an element from the page, modify it and then place it back with any standard jQuery methods like [jQuery.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and many other.

If you use `datatype: 'json'` and `gridview: true` the *full* body of grid will be constructed as string and then placed in the grid as *one insert operation*. So you will get much more better performance as with `addRowData` in case of many inserted rows.

**UPDATED**: On [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DebaprasadJana.htm) I show how the loading of the data directly in jqGrid can be implemented. I recommend you to use [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) or [custom](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) jqGrid formatters. For example to be able correctly sort the data one have to include date in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and use `formatter: 'date'` with the corresponding options to display the date.

Additionally I don't recommend you to use spaces inside of ID. I supposed that `VEHICLE_ID` is unique `id` of your data. I used it, but removed all spaces from the value.

About the usage function inside of `postData` I recommend you to read my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935).

The most important part of the code of the demo you find below

```
var maintainerValue = 1, showValue = 200, $grid = $("#list");

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'DebaprasadJana.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {
        maintainer: function () {
            // if maintainerValue will be get from a field on the page
            // one can get the data here directly like
            //     return $("#maintainer").val();
            return maintainerValue;
        },
        show: function () {
            return showValue;
        }
    },
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: function (obj) {
            // we can use VEHICLE_ID as the rowid, but cut spaces
            return obj.VEHICLE_ID.replace(/\s/g, '');
        },
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    }
});
$("#reload").click(function () {
    // next two lines simulate reading of the
    // current values of maintainerValue and showValue 
    maintainerValue++;
    showValue--;
    // we need reset datatype only if we use loadonce:true
    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'})
        .trigger('reloadGrid');
});
```

Comment: I have edited the question for your better understanding.Please have a look at this edited version and help me solving this.

Comment: Many many thanks. You gave an excellent solution. i was working with your code. Now my code giving no error after integrating your solution in my code. thanks once again.